# How to display a message box on wpf textblock validation error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, messagebox

I have implemented a validation for Datagrid cell template using IDataErrorInfo and can able to show a tooltip error message. How can i display a messagebox with error information instead of tooltip?

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code" MinWidth="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>

  <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                 <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

IDataErrorInfo implemented class

```
public class CurrencyExchangeRate : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _code;
    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
             if (_code != value)
            {
                _code = value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code))
                {
                    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Code");
                }
            }
        }
    }  

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = string.Empty;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Code":

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code))
                    {
                        error = "Code cannot be empty";
                        ShowMessage(error);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }  
    public static void ShowMessage(string error)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(error);
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: You surely have to use code behind, XAML can't help in this case.

Comment: I have a ViewModel implemented. How to get the error information in the ViewModel whenever error is occurred?

Comment: In indexer where you set your error content display Messagebox.

Comment: @Maximus when set the display MessageBox in indexer MessageBox displays more than once. How to display only once like whenever user leave the textblock or something?

Comment: What kind of message box you want to display? any screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class implementing IDataErrorInfo add in indexer MessageBox. In order to show it only once after leaving TextBox set

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

it will provide checking validation after losing focus.

Comment: I updated the code with the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus. However it displays twice.

Comment: First time when apply second on validation, am I right?

Comment: _code should be checked,  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code))

Comment: Corrected. It seems to be first time displayed on Lost Focus and second time appears after click 'Ok' button of the first message box.

Comment: Why are you using Dispatcher? If your ViewModel is a DataContext of View it works on UI.

Comment: I used dispatcher to display a message box from model class indexer intead of ViewModel.

Comment: No..still displaying message twice.

Comment: Model class is not supposed to display MessageBox. Consider displaying error text in for instance TextBlock not MessageBox but if you persist to choose it add breakpoint to invoking ShowMessage and see when it is invoked precisely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59989/discussion-between-chenk-and-maximus).

Comment: I figured out that Indexer is calling twice when the property updates. Therefore i have added a condition for RaisePropertyChangedEvent which trigger only when property value is not null or empty. Thank you @Maximus for your help.